# glMatrix.toRadian(x)

Tags: javascript

So, I've been trying to find a solution to this error: 'toRadian' is not defined.
I'm not using the minified version of glMatrix, and I am using version 3.0.0

Code: `glMatrix.mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, toRadian(45), canvas.width / canvas.height, .1, 1000.);`

I've went through the source, and it is there. I'm not sure why this is happening but for right now, I've had to hardcode: `45 * Math.PI / 180`, which I shouldn't really be doing because it just looks awful.

If someone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience using glMatrix, but from what I can read in the [documentation](http://glmatrix.net/docs/module-glMatrix.html), `toRadian` is a proberty of `glMatrix` and not a global variable, so unless you somehow changed it's scope you'll have to write `glMatrix.toRadian` instead.

Another approach would be to add `toRadian` to the global scope:

```
window.toRadian = glMatrix.toRadian;
```

This should allow you to access the function just as you did in your example.

Comment: Just found out that it's `glMatrix.glMatrix.toRadian(x);`
Not sure why they'd change it without updating the documentation but found it. 
Thanks for your suggestion anyway :)

Comment: Well, they actually do say so in their documentation - toRadian is a function of the glMatrix module, and that is stored in glMatrix just like mat4. I just assumed it would be directly on the global object :|

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: `glMatrix.glMatrix.toRadian(x);`. 
Not sure why they'd change it without providing new documentation but here you go if you need it :)

Answer (score 0):

glMatrix is more convenient to use as an ES6 module.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "gl-matrix": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/gl-matrix@3.4.3"
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="module">
        import { mat4, vec3, glMatrix } from "gl-matrix";

        function main() {
            // Conversion from degrees to radians
            const rad = glMatrix.toRadian(180);
            console.log(`radians = ${rad}`);
            // output: radians = 3.141592653589793

            // Identity matrix
            const m = mat4.create();
            console.log(`matrix = ${m}`);
            // output: matrix = 1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1

            // Vector addition
            const a = vec3.fromValues(1, 2, 3);
            const b = vec3.fromValues(4, 5, 6);
            const result = vec3.create();
            vec3.add(result, a, b);
            console.log(`result = ${result}`);
            // output: result = 5,7,9
        }
        main();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```